# Как определить размер нестандартного файла /dev/urandom?

Tags: linux, c, ubuntu, файлы

В общем пишу проект по операционным системам на C.
Есть код, который считывает информацию из файла и передаёт её дальше в обработку.
Так вот информацию из /dev/urandom он читает нормально, но неопределённо долго.
Дело в том, что у меня код опирается на статичный буфер и мне нужно его размер подобрать так, чтобы этот файл вместился.

Так вот вопрос:

Как узнать размер нестандартного файла, каким является /dev/urandom?

Является ли он конечным или этот файл генерирует каждый раз новое сочетание при обращении к нему?

Comment: Я не понимаю как можно написать столько букв прежде чем просто написать в поисковик? https://yandex.ru/search/?lr=213&text=%2Fdev%2Furandom

Comment: Меня интересовал больше первый вопрос, так как не понятен размер файла в ноль..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

/dev/urandom не занимает место на диске. данные там каждый раз новые при каждом чтении - обращении.

Скорее всего у вас неправильный код для оценки размера файла.

```
$ du /dev/urandom
0   /dev/urandom
```

Comment: Я уже вычитал, что он возвращает запрашиваемое количество байтов. Код написал правильный, просто меня смутило число 0. Дело в том, что меня интересовал именно фактический размер этого файла, а теперь я начинаю понимать, что это нестандартный файл в том смысле, что это просто так называемая "ссылка".

Comment: это даже не ссылка, ссылка хранится на диске и занимает один блок

Comment: Поэтому я взял это слово в кавычки.

Comment: @Алексей Почему же не стандартный? Стандарт описывает пять типов файлов (регулярный, каталог, символическая ссылка, сокет, файл устройства), это один из них, разве не так? Почитайте книги, на худой конец начните с `man stat` и `man ls`.

Comment: Хорошо, трудности перевода, давайте так: this is not a regular file (то есть нерегулярный).